# Should we request migrate on low quality questions, with low quality answers, (from other sites)

Tags: discussion, migration

Occationally other SE sites in the past have had things slip through.
Like this one: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929267/portable-windows-mosh/20952213#20952213

We have set the bar for quality quiet high, 
and I wouldn't be very happy seeing its answers on this site.
(even my answer to it.)

Now that we are in public beta we can flag, and use the "*other (needs ♦ moderator attention)*" option to request a question be migrated.

Answer (score 5):

## No.

First of all, questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated.

Second, migrations to beta sites are strongly discouraged, for several reasons:

- If the site doesn't graduate, then questions that would have existed elsewhere on the network are lost.
- Migrated questions have a strong possibility of changing the feel and direction of the site in its early stages of growth. Questions should be specifically tailored to the site, in order for the site's scope to clearly and organically evolve.
- Beta sites need to prove themselves, and grow their membership and community naturally. "Poaching" questions from other sites stunts the new site's growth. In order to graduate, a beta site must be able to attract interest on its own, without taking questions from established sites.

**I'm a moderator on Super User**, and I would reject any flag requesting migration to Software Recs (or any other beta site).

Comment: I agree, thank you for enunciating it clearly

Answer (score 5):

[In addition to what @nhinkle said](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/658/125)...

There's a very simple rule for situations like this

[Never migrate crap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82986/135565)

*Assuming* we're a open migration path *and* someone migrates crap, we'll likely reject it and kick it back - we're not anyone's dustbin. If you think its potentially a good question, with a tool you're going to use, why not simply ask a new, high quality question? It would be much more useful that way. If you *really* want to migrate it, fixing up the question and answers would be another option *pre* migration. Give us something we'd feel comfortable with having on the site before sending it over.

I'd add that SF had requested that they be removed as an automatic option from SO cause of too much crap coming their way, so migrating crap would probably have consequences for the source site. If nothing else, folks who're regular here will be rejecting a lot more migrations.

Practically speaking though, you could take the route SF, SU and a few other sites go, and check with a mod on software recommendations.